# hierarchy of textboxes in vb.net (from left to right)

Tags: vb.net

[when you press tab key, the textbox hierarchy should be from left to right. what codes will I use for this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmPnE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baWwS.png)

Comment: Hi Melo, do take a look at our [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently it is unclear what it is that you need help with.

Comment: take a look at the picture, that should be the hierarchy of textboxes

Comment: `Textbox.TabIndex` is your friend

Comment: i tried Textbox.TabIndex=1 and so on. but it's not working

Comment: Private Sub TextBox34_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox34.TextChanged
        TextBox34.TabIndex = 12
    End Sub

Comment: When you create your Form (in design mode), you must specify the TabIndex value from 1 for the first element, 2 for the second... In RunTime mode, the item with TabIndex = 1 will be focused